# A proof of a property of positive element in $C^{*}$-algebra.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

In W.Rudin's book P295, Theorem 11.28 is about the positive element(i.e. $a\geq 0$), the property: $\mathscr{A}$ is $C^{*}$-algebra,

(e)If $a\in \mathscr{A}$, then $aa^{*}\geq 0$.

(f)If $a\in \mathscr{A}$, then $e+aa^{*}$ is invertible in $\mathscr{A}$.

Q1: I have other ways to approach the (e), but I do not totally sure it works. 
My method is in the same way of W.Rudin at the beginning, considering the Gelfand transform $\Gamma$ in a maximal normal set of $a$ $\mathscr{B}\subset \mathscr{A}$, we have

$$\Gamma(aa^{*})=\Gamma(a)\Gamma(a^{*})=\vert \Gamma(a)\vert^{2} \geq 0,$$
then $aa^{*} \geq 0.$

Q2: How to use the (e) to show (f)?

$e+aa^{*}$ is invertible if and only if $\Vert aa^{*}\Vert \leq 1$.How to use it to show the (f)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your first question, there isn't necessarily a maximal normal set containing $a$.  The reason for this is because generally $a$ doesn't commute with $a^*$.  Thus we have a bit more work to prove that $aa^*\geq0$ (hence the longer proof in Rudin).

For your second question, let $\mathscr B$ denote the C$^*$-subalgebra of $\mathscr A$ generated by $aa^*$ (or the maximal normal set containing $aa^*$, if you prefer).  Note that if $e+aa^*$ is invertible in $\mathscr B$, then $e+aa^*$ is invertible in $\mathscr A$.  Furthermore, $e+aa^*$ is invertible in $\mathscr B$ if and only if $\gamma(e+aa^*)\neq0$ for all complex homomorphisms $\gamma$ on $\mathscr B$ (for then $0\notin\sigma_\mathscr{B}(e+aa^*)$).  But we have 
$$\gamma(e+aa^*)=\gamma(e)+\gamma(aa^*)\geq1+0>0$$
for all complex homomorphisms $\gamma$, and the result follows.

Comment: What is about the Q1? Is it right?

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to look at that.  But yes it looks fine.

Comment: But why is the method in Rudin's so long?  I am not sure.

Comment: Oh nevermind, it's not alright.  Sorry, I don't know what I was thinking. I'll edit my answer to explain.

Comment: Since $a$ is positive(i.e. $a=a^{*}$ ), $a$ commutes with $a^{*}$( because $aa^{*}=a^2=a^{*}a$). Is it right?

Comment: No, $a$ is just any element of $\mathscr A$.  It is shown that $aa^*$ is always positive.

Comment: But if I consider the maximal normal set of $a$?

Comment: Unless $a$ is normal (which, is general, it isn't), any set containing $a$ is not normal.

Comment: Oh! I see! Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.  Glad to help!